# AS3, Getting the class in which some method is defined

Tags: reflection, actionscript, actionscript-3, static-methods

In ActionScript 3.
Given some method! Is there a way to get the class that's defining my method (at runtime).
Furthermore the method is static.
Looked at http://www.as3commons.org/ but doesn't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: **No, there's no way to do this in ActionScript**.
Most presumably for security reasons. If you pass a method closure (e.g. event handler) to an ApplicationDomain that has to be considered insecure, you don't want code from there to find the owner and possibly start crawling your whole object graph.

On the other hand, this might help: [Actionscript-3 namespaces and dynamic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162917/actionscript-3-namespaces-and-dynamic-types/3164737#3164737)

greetz
back2dos